# ImportError from different apps

Tags: python, django

I am importing the models from different apps but I am getting this error and I am not sure why this is occurring.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/Spark/users/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from notifications.models import Notification
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/Spark/notifications/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from users.models import UserProfile
ImportError: cannot import name UserProfile
```

my notifications/models:

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import UserProfile
from restaurants.models import Restaurant

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my users/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from notifications.models import Notification

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: okay, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are the victim of circular import dependency. In order to resolve this, you need to tell Django the import path of the model in `ForeignKey` instead of actually importing it:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile')
```

Also don't forget to delete import statement from `from users.models import UserProfile` from *notifications/models.py*.

Answer (score 1):

You have circular dependencies loop.

`User` imports `Notification` and `Notification` imports `User`.

Just remove `from notifications.models import Notification` from your `users/models.py`